# dismissModalViewController in message passing between view controllers

Tags: iphone

I was just wondering if this is a correct way of passing data or messages between different views in iphone/ipad.

I have two ViewControllers, FirstViewController and SecondViewController. I have an NSString *message as a property in both my ViewControllers which I set in the following way.

in FirstViewController.h, I import the class SecondViewController.h. I have this IBAction that gets called when user taps a button on the first view

```
-(IBAction)ShowSecondView
{

    SeondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    secondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    secondView.message = @"Presented from First View";

    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];

    [secondView release];

}
```

In my SecondViewController.h, I import the class FirstViewController.h
I have this IBAction that gets called when user taps a button on second view

```
-(IBAction)GoBack
{ 

    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    firstView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    firstView.message = @"Presented from Second View";

    [self presentModalViewController:firstView animated:YES];

    [firstView release];

}
```

The messages are successfully passed between the views but if I use 
`[self dismissModalViewController]` in order to dismiss the current view controller to go back to the parent view  in, the message is not passed.

Comment: my suggestion is using delegate

Answer (score 0):

While dismissing a modal view controller, no data will be sent. You can write some protocols and give back the value to the parent view using delegate mechanism, before dismissing the view.

For more info, see [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html)

[Basics of protocol and delegate in Objective-C](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your firstView alloc'd in GoBack is not the first view controller that presented the second view controller. It's a new instance of the FirstViewController class. Instead of creating this firstView instance you want to simply dismiss the second view controller. But you'll also want to create a pointer to the first view controller in your second view controller so that you can set data in it.

in the header of your second view controller:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
FirstViewController *firstView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) firstViewController *firstView;
```

in the implementation of your second view controller:

```
@synthesize firstView;
```

in your first view controller:

```
-(IBAction)ShowSecondView {
    SeondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    secondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    secondView.message = @"Presented from First View";
    secondView.firstView = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    [secondView release];
}
```

in your second view controller:

```
-(IBAction)GoBack { 
    firstView.message = @"Presented from Second View";
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

btw, there are other ways to communicate between viewcontrollers, I often use [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

btw, code above is untested straight outta my head. apologies if there's any faults with it.

Comment: This will cause the "cyclic import" problem. Any ways i'll use either notifications or delegates. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It doesn't cause "cyclic import" problems. In this approach the first ViewController imports the second, but the second doesn't import the first (it dismisses itself to return to the original first).